# Can't rm or cd into directory

Tags: macos, rm

I found a directory on my machine called "Previous System" that looked old and useless and I tried to delete by dragging to the trash and emptying the trash. That failed to delete the directory, because emptying the trash gave me messages such as `The file 'Applications' is in use.` or `The file '.MobileBackups' is in use.`

So I dragged that directory out of the trash and went into the terminal to delete it, but it seems undeletable. For example:

```
$ cd ~/Desktop
$ sudo mv Previous\ System prevsys
$ sudo rm -rf prevsys
rm: prevsys/.MobileBackups/Computer/2014-10-20-143930/Volume/Applications/CrashPlan.app: Operation not permitted
rm: prevsys/.MobileBackups/Computer/2014-10-20-143930/Volume/Applications: Directory not empty
rm: prevsys/.MobileBackups/Computer/2014-10-20-143930/Volume: Directory not empty 
rm: prevsys/.MobileBackups/Computer/2014-10-20-143930: Directory not empty
rm: prevsys/.MobileBackups/Computer: Directory not empty
rm: prevsys/.MobileBackups: Directory not empty
rm: prevsys: Directory not empty
$ cd prevsys
$ sudo ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 root  wheel  102 Nov 18  2013 .MobileBackups
$ sudo cd .MobileBackups
$ pwd
/Users/blah/Desktop/prevsys
```

I've never seen a directory that I can't `cd` into as the superuser, so I'm not really sure, how do I get rid of this thing? Thanks.

Comment: try `lsof` to see what applications are using that directory.

Comment: Crashplan is still running; you need to stop it before you can delete a directory it is using.

Comment: In situations like this, I like to look at the output of `ls -laeO@` (that's a little ell and a capital oh). Those options will show you hidden files, ACLs, file flags, and extended attributes.

Comment: You cannot use `cd` with `sudo` like that.  What happens is that `sudo` starts a new process which does change directory, but then it exits without doing anything else, and your prompt is left at the same directory.  You can try `sudo -i` to launch a prompt that is running as root.

Comment: Not sure what this means...
    `$ls -laeO@
    total 0
    drwxrwxr-x@ 3 jayharris  admin  -         102 Oct 20 14:15 .
 com.apple.s stem.Security  68
     0: group:everyone deny delete
    drwxr-xr-x@ 3 root       wheel  -         102 Mar 27 09:40 ..
  com.apple.backupd.SnapshotVolumeFSEventStoreUUID  36
 com.apple.backupd.SnapshotVolumeLastFSEventID   8
 com.apple.backupd.SnapshotVolumeUUID  36
    drwxrwxr-x  2 jayharris  staff  schg,uchg  68 Mar 26  2012 CrashPlan.app`

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sudo -i
$ cd prevsys/.MobileBackups/Computer/2014-10-20-143930/Volume/Applications
$ chflags noschg CrashPlan.app
$ chflags nouchg CrashPlan.app
$ cd ~/Desktop
$ rm -rf prevsys
```

The problem was that the CrashPlan.app directory, with CrashPlan running or not, had a "system immutable" flag (`schg`) and a "user immutable" flag (`uchg`) attached to it. The two `chflags` commands turn off those flags (by appending "no" to the name of the flag), then once those are turned off, the whole stupid directory could be removed.

Thanks.